# How to calculate total charge going through a coil, when its rotated in a uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

A conductive coil has *N* turns of loops with a radius *r*, and it has a resistance *R*. The coil is initially in an external homogenous magnetic field *B*, perpendicular to it. The direction of the magnetic field is reversed in time *t*.

How can I calculate the total charge going through the coil?

I imagine I first have to apply the Faraday's law of induction to get the *emf* ($\mathcal{E}$). This I did so that I first calculated the magnetic flux

$$\Phi_B = \int B \;dA = B \pi r^2 \left( \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \cos(\theta) \;d\theta + \int\limits_{\pi/2}^\pi \cos(\theta) \;d\theta \right) = -2B\pi r^2$$

Then I calculated the *emf* using the equation

$$\mathcal{E} = -N \frac{\Delta \Phi_B}{\Delta t}$$

where simply $\Delta \Phi_B = \Phi_B$ and $\Delta t = t$.

I know that the *emf* is defined as the work done on a unit charge to move it once around a conductive loop, and it can be written as

$$\mathcal{E} = \frac{Fl}{q} = \frac{F2\pi r}{q}$$

but I just can't figure out how to get the total amount of charge from this. I haven't taken the resistance of the coil into account yet, so maybe that's one factor.

Can you point out what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Is the magnetic field perpendicular to the axis of the coil or the plane in which the loops are located?

Comment: Perpendicular to the plane of the loops, I think. The expression is not entirely clear, but I imagine the magnetic field is going straight through the loops in the initial configuration.

Comment: If the coil is shorted, then the general equation for current can be used $L\dot {I}+RI=emf$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to write $emf = Ri$ and integrate over time since $i=dQ/dt$.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. Seems like I just had a wrong way of looking at the _emf_ definition.